# How to make latex write to stdout

Tags: shell-script, pipe, latex

I'm trying to create a shell script which converts latex-formulas to svgs. I want to use `latex` and `dvisvgm`.

But I want to use as few tempfiles as possible.

Is there a way to make latex write the dvi file to stdout?

I haven't found a corresponding option in the manpage, but is there maybe a general "shell way" of redirecting output that is supposed to go to a file to stdout?

Comment: What's the issue with the temporary files?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com may be also relevant. But as far I know it is not possible (OTOH there are many "latex" engines). And latex will create various temporary file (for indices, toc, etc), so at the end, your efford may be just for nothing

Comment: Possibly relevant answer on the TeX SE site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11526

Answer (score 0):

As LaTeX *really* creates copious amounts of temporary files anyway, you can't win anything here.

Also, outputting to stdout whilst suppressing the usual output to stdout would require changing things in the TeX core. That won't happen, so I'm afraid what you want is impossible.

> I'm trying to create a shell script which converts latex-formulas to svgs.

For formulas only, there's relatively mature options that offer you a server that does that. Look into katex.org. The advantages would be speed and security (honestly, `--write18` is probably disabled for you, anyway, but LaTeX is really not a piece of software I'd consider "safe for untrusted user input", not even "securable", without basically writing your own restricted TeX parser, which then as well might get a small rendering add on itself...).